# Cleaning up WordPress thumbnails; trying to find all thumbnails and delete them on Ubuntu 22

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

So, I'm trying to clean up some backups I have, and they're getting bigger and bigger because of, mainly, the number of thumbnails generated by WordPress per image. I came close to finding a solution, but, naturally, there are a few outliers that make my solution not work, and I can't figure out either the proper regular expression or an alternative way to handle this.

Currently, I am going this route:

First, find all the images: `find . -regex '.*[a-z]-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.(png|jpg|webp)' | xargs ls`

Then, I'd delete them like so: `find . -regex '.*[a-z]-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.(png|jpg|webp)' | xargs rm -f`

This would work fine for thumbnails such as `seo-magnifier-256x256.png`.

However, the outliers are favicons such as images as `favicon-16x16.png`, `apple-touch-icon-114x114.png`, `mstile-150x150.png`, and `android-chrome-512x512.png` (there are more with different dimensions).

So, I was trying to figure out the regex to exclude images that started with `(favicon|apple-touch-icon|mstile|android-chrome)` but I can't seem to get it.

Would anyone be able to help me out in determining the proper regex or a better way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do:

```
$ ls -1
apple-touch-icon-magnifier-256x256.png
favicon-magnifier-256x256.png
seo-magnifier-256x256.png
```

```
$ find . -regextype egrep \
    -not -regex '.*/(favicon|apple-touch-icon|mstile|android-chrome).*' \
    -regex '.*[a-z]-[0-9]+x[0-9]+\.(png|jpg|webp)' \
```

```
./seo-magnifier-256x256.png
```

Finally, to delete if you are happy with the result, append `-delete` to the end of `find`'s command.